# MySql Left Join very slow query

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-slow-query-log

i have 2 tables of about 3000/4000 rows. I need to make a relation using Left Join for filter the results by searching a text or datetime. I need also to count a total row for pagination. When i run the query is epic slow, consider about 40/45 seconds by console and more than a minute from webpage.
The relation is: for 1 of tableA have N in tableB.
There is a solution for have a fast query? 
The sample query is:

```
SELECT X,Y,Z, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM tableB WHERE tableB.idTa=tableA.id) AS CountTB 
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.idA
WHERE tableA.X LIKE'%mytext%' OR tableB.Z LIKE'%mytext%' 
GROUP BY tableA.id 
ORDER BY tableA.Y LIMIT 0,10
```

Thank you all

ON clause is present of course. only mistyped from my phone. Now it's correct and very slow :)

New update:
If I change the relationship from LEFT JOIN to RIGHT JOIN it become pretty fast....why??

Comment: you missed `ON` clause for join. so this query not slow. it is broken

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` ought to be using `ON` or `USING`, not `WHERE`.  You should not need that nested-`SELECT`.  That's where your time is going.

Comment: That `LIKE` avoid index, so you should consider [**FULL TEXT**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) instead.

Comment: also not filtering with "WHERE LIKE" is too slow

Answer (score 2):

Start from correct `JOIN` I believe that should work pretty fast.

Something like:

```
SELECT a.X,a.Y,a.Z, COUNT(b.id)  CountTB 
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b
ON b.idTa = a.id AND b.Z LIKE'%mytext%' 
WHERE a.X LIKE '%mytext%'
GROUP BY tableA.id 
ORDER BY tableA.Y LIMIT 0,10
```

Your conditions are not very clear. If you can provide good data sample, we can find better query.

I have a guess that you don't need to `b.Z LIKE'%mytext%'`. start from just:

```
SELECT a.X,a.Y,a.Z, COUNT(b.id)  CountTB 
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b
ON b.idTa = a.id 
WHERE a.X LIKE '%mytext%'
GROUP BY tableA.id 
ORDER BY tableA.Y LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: *Hmm,* I was not aware that you could use `AND` in an `ON`-clause like that.

Comment: Yes `AND` can be used in `ON`.  But don't do it in this case.  Use `ON` to specify how the tables are related; use `WHERE` to filter.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a wild stab at this, just to point you in the general direction, here's a *possible* rewrite of that query: *(I don't promise that it works ...)*

```
SELECT X,Y,Z, COUNT(B.id) AS CountTB
FROM tableA A
  LEFT JOIN tableB B
    USING (id)
WHERE tableA.X LIKE'%mytext%' OR tableB.Z LIKE'%mytext%' 
GROUP BY X, Y, Z
ORDER BY tableA.Y 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Notice my many changes:

1. There is no nested query.
2. The tables are identified for convenience by the alises, `A` and `B`.
3. The `LEFT JOIN` is `USING (id)`, which is shorthand for `WHERE A.id = B.id`.
4. The `GROUP BY` clause specifies that the data is to be grouped by these three variables.  All of these must appear in the `SELECT` clause, and everything *else* that appears must be an aggregate function such as `COUNT()` or `SUM()`.

Again, *I do not promise that this query works.*  But it should illustrate how such a query should generally be constructed.

Comment: you can't `USING (id)` because in original post we have `WHERE tableB.idTa=tableA.id` so **idTa!=id**

Comment: "Right you are!" Good catch!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `LEFT` unless you want `NULLs` from the 'righthand' table.  I don't think you do in this case.

The positioning of the `( SELECT COUNT... )` means that it needs to be re-evaluated for ever row, which it does not.  Get rid of it; use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

A.X and B.Z are being searched for the *same* substring?  Do they always have the same value?  If so, then only search one of them.  (`LIKE '%...'` is a costly part of your query.)

Using `JOIN` inflates the number of rows; then you added `GROUP BY` to deflate it.  This inflate/deflate is costly.

The `COUNT(*)` fails to filter by '%mytext%', so it won't give you what you want for "rows 30-39 of 145".

Is it A.Z or B.Z??

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
        a.X, a.Y,
        ( SELECT Z FROM tableB WHERE idTa = a.id AND Z LIKE'%mytext%' ) AS Z
    FROM tableA AS a
    WHERE a.X LIKE '%mytext%'
    ORDER BY a.Y
    LIMIT 0,10

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();   -- to get the "of 156 rows"
```

and you need these

```
tableB: INDEX(idTa)
tableA: INDEX(Y)
```

Caveat:  Since it is unclear what the relationship between A and B is (1:many vs many:many), this solution may be incorrect.  The incorrectness will jump out by the subquery returning multiple rows.

So, I may not have given you the 'correct' answer, but hopefully I have given you enough clues so you can get much closer.

After that, perhaps you can make the pagination faster by "remembering where you left off" instead of using `OFFSET`.  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

If you want to discuss this further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and do not obfuscate the column names -- often the names give clues of your intent.